# How to display french letters?

Tags: vbscript, hta

```xml
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>

<script language = "VBScript">
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Sub Window_onLoad
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("fr.yml", 1)
  row = 0
  Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    'Msgbox(file.Readline)
    line = file.Readline
    dict.Add row, line
    row = row + 1
  Loop
  nnn.innerHTML = dict(15)
  hhh.innerHTML = "prêt àprêt à"
End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p id="nnn">éprêt à</p>
<p id="hhh">éprêt à</p>
</body>
```

In this code the `<p id="nnn">` shows `TerminÃ©` like this, and `<p id="hhh">` shows `prêt àprêt à` like this exactly.

My fr.yml file has 16th line `Terminé`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input file (`fr.yml`) appears to be UTF-8 encoded. `FileSystemObject` methods can't handle that encoding, so you need to use an `ADODB.Stream`, as @Ekkehard.Horner suggested:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 2 'text
stream.Charset = "utf-8"
stream.LoadFromFile "fr.yml"
For Each line In Split(stream.ReadText, vbNewLine)
  dict.Add row, line
  row = row + 1
Next
stream.Close
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Thank you for that. But i found answer for my question by my self later. Since my mistake was small i preferred to use mine. Thank you any way. your codeworks too.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by my self by adding one more parameter to `OpenTextFile()`.

```
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Sub Window_onLoad
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("fr.yml", 1, -1)
  row = 0
  Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    'Msgbox(file.Readline)
    line = file.Readline
    dict.Add row, line
    row = row + 1
  Loop
  nnn.innerHTML = dict(15)
  hhh.innerHTML = "prêt àprêt à"
End Sub
```

Reference [Here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14075)