# VBS - Weird Japanese characters conversion

Tags: vbscript

I've been searching Google and StackOverflow and did find some partial answers to my problem. Here is my question:

I've bee n trying to make a small script that will promt the user for keywords and once you hit enter it will parse the array into Chrome or Firefox and open up tabs with all the various searches. It works! But, then I wanted to expand on that so I could make a .txt file and make it read from that, that works too! BUT since it's a Japanese site we're searching, Japanese will yield better results!

So I got the ForReading and TriState/Unicode = -1 to work, and it does issue something in Japanese, the problem is it doesn't issue the characters I inserted into the document. :/ And I'm at a loss at the moment. Here's the part of the code that I need some help with:

```
'Declaring
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const Unicode = -1
Dim FullPath
Dim objShell
Dim SearchArray
Dim Figure
Dim Index
Dim listWord
Dim Mandarake
Dim invalidName
Dim rawImport
Dim objFSO
Dim objTextFile
FullPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FullPath&"\mandalist.txt", ForReading,True,Unicode)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
SearchArray = Array()
mandarake = "http://ekizo.mandarake.co.jp/shop/en"
'Starting do loop until we trigger the search with "go"
Do
    ReDim Preserve SearchArray(UBound(SearchArray)+1)
    Figure = InputBox("Enter a name or type 'go' when you're done!", "Figure search", "List")
    SearchArray(UBound(SearchArray)) = "http://ekizo.mandarake.co.jp/shop/en/search.do?action=keyword&doujin=all&keyword="&Replace(Figure," ","+")
'Trying to handle empty or "Name" entry into array error
        If Figure = Empty Then 
            invalidName = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit?",1,"Are you sure?")
                If invalidName = vbOK Then
                    WScript.Quit (0)
                End If
    ElseIf Figure = "List" Then
        Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
            rawImport = objTextFile.Readline
            Figure = Replace(rawImport," ","+")
            SearchArray = Split(Figure , ",")
            Call objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", mandarake, "", "", 1)
                For Index = 0 To UBound(SearchArray)
                    Call objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "http://ekizo.mandarake.co.jp/shop/en/search.do?action=keyword&doujin=all&keyword="&SearchArray(index), "", "", 1)
                    WScript.Sleep(1500)
            Next
            WScript.Quit (0)
        Loop
```

I have more code hence all the dims and set's, but that is if the If Figure = "List" is not true and it will then continue to the insertion of manual keywords, and those works even with Japanese signs. The thing is, no matter what I paste into the text file it will parse other characters (also some Japanese stuff) into the URL instead of what I put in. How can I get it to treat the charset as it's supposed to?

Example would be:

Text in Mandalist.txt = グリフォン アスナ
Text in URL in Chrome = 믯낂菣閃苣뎃ꊂ苣誃 - HMF :s

Any help would be much appreciated.

PS - This is my first project where I don't rely on a piece of paper that my teacher wrote me in school, so it may be simple but I just can't make it work.

Thanks
/CuraeL

Comment: Text in URL in Chrome starts with  the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`, typical `UTF-8` byte order mark (by _Unicode Analyzer_ extension for Google Chrome). IMHO VBScript has no intrinsic method for handling   `UTF-8` encoded files; it's _Unicode_ (`Const Unicode = -1`) means UTF-16.

Comment: See @Ansgar's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28499456/603855  to see how to use ADODB.Stream to read UTF-8.

Comment: @Ekkerd.Horner: Thank you so much for your answer! Awesome. That explanation totally worked. I loaded in the stream and rewrote my previous script around that and it just did the trick! Thanks for learning me that..!